# Model Generic Class for JSON Object structure

Tags: java, json, model, jackson

I need to read the following `JSON` format into my model classes, I am able to do it but I would like to remove the dependency of knowing different branch locations such as `nyc`, `boston`.

**I am confused how to modify this implementation to read the JSONObject**

I would like to make it `Generic` so that it can read new branch information without any code changes. Example: `charlotte`. Other JSON structure would remain standard for my case. I am using `Builder` Pattern in my `Model` classes.

**Note: If there are any suggestions to modify the `JSON` structure to accommodate new locations, so that the implementation becomes `Generic` I am open to discussion.**

This is the JSON that I am working on:

```
{
  "company": "abc inc",
  "logoUrl": "someUrl",
  "phone": "1234567890",
  "branch": {
    "nyc": {
      "products": {
        "asian": {
          "somekey1": "someValue1",
          "somekeyN": "somevalueN"
        },
        "american": {
          "somekey1": "someValue1",
          "somekeyN": "somevalueN"
        }
      }
    },
    "boston": {
      "products": {
        "asian": {
          "somekey1": "somevalue1",
          "somekeyN": "somevalueN"
        },
        "american": {
          "somekey1": "somevalue1",
          "somekeyN": "somevalueN"
        }
      }
    },
    "charlotte": {
      "products": {
        "asian": {
          "somekey1": "somevalue1",
          "somekeyN": "somevalueN"
        },
        "american": {
          "somekey1": "somevalue1",
          "somekeyN": "somevalueN"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here are my Model Classes:

```
@JsonDeserialize( builder = Content.Builder.class)
public class Content {

    private final String company;
    private final String logoUrl;
    private final String phone;
    private final Branch branch;


    private Content(Builder builder){
        this.company = builder.company;
        this.logoUrl = builder.logoUrl;
        this.phone = builder.phone;
        this.branch = builder.branch;
    }

    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public String getLogoUrl() {
        return logoUrl;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public Branch getBranch() {
        return branch;
    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties( ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class Builder {
        private String company;
        private String logoUrl;
        private String phone;
        private Branch branch;

        @JsonProperty("company")
        public Builder withCompany(String company){
            this.company = company;
            return this;
        }

        @JsonProperty("logoUrl")
        public Builder withLogoUrl(String logoUrl){
            this.logoUrl = logoUrl;
            return this;
        }

        @JsonProperty("phone")
        public Builder withPhone(String phone){
            this.phone = phone;
            return this;
        }

        @JsonProperty("branch")
        public Builder withBranch(Branch branch) {
            this.branch = branch;
            return this;
        }
        public Content build(){
            return new Content(this);
        }
    }
}
```

In `Branch` Model class I would like to remove the dependency of adding new location example `charlotte` and make this Generic. How can I make this work, so that I don't need to use `@JsonProperty("nyc")` and any new location would be read and mapped.

```
@JsonDeserialize( builder = Branch.Builder.class)
public class Branch {

    private final Nyc nyc;
    private final Boston boston;

    private Branch(Builder builder){
        this.boston = builder.boston;
        this.nyc = builder.nyc;
    }

    public Nyc getNyc() {
        return nyc;
    }
    public Boston getBoston() {
        return boston;
    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties( ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class Builder{
        private Nyc nyc;
        private Boston boston;

        @JsonProperty("nyc")
        public Builder withNyc(Nyc nyc){
            this.nyc = nyc;
            return this;
        }

        @JsonProperty("boston")
        public Builder withBoston(Boston boston){
            this.boston = boston;
            return this;
        }

        public Branch build(){
            return new Branch(this);
        }
    }
}

@JsonDeserialize(builder = Products.Builder.class)
public class Products {

    private final Map<String,String> asian;
    private final Map<String,String> american;

    public Products(Builder builder){
        this.asian = builder.asian;
        this.american = builder.american;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getAsian() {
        return asian;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getAmerican() {
        return american;
    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class Builder {
        private Map<String,String> asian;
        private Map<String,String> american;

        @JsonProperty("asian")
        public Builder withAsian(Map<String,String> asian){
            this.asian = asian;
            return this;
        }

        @JsonProperty("american")
        public Builder withAmerican(Map<String,String> american){
            this.american = american;
            return this;
        }

        public Products build(){
           return  new Products(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Other Model classes:

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Boston.Builder.class)
public class Boston {

    private final Products products;

    private Boston(Builder builder){
        this.products = builder.products;
    }

    public Products getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties( ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class Builder {
        private Products products;

        @JsonProperty("products")
        public Builder withProducts(Products products){
            this.products = products;
            return this;
        }

        public Boston build(){
            return new Boston(this);
        }
    }
}

@JsonDeserialize(builder = Nyc.Builder.class)
public class Nyc {

    private final Products products;

    private Nyc(Builder builder){
        this.products = builder.products;
    }

    public Products getProducts() {
        return products;
    }


    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class Builder{
        private Products products;

        @JsonProperty("products")
        public Builder withProducts(Products products){
            this.products = products;
            return this;
        }

        public Nyc build(){
            return new Nyc(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public class ReadJSON {
  public static void main(String[] args)
      throws IOException
  {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    Content content = mapper.readValue(new File("content.json"), Content.class);
    mapper.writeValue(System.out,content);
  }
}
```

Comment: The Branch class should define an ArrayList<Location> instead of having each Location as a separate attribute (nyc, boston, etc). In that way you could make all this generic.

Comment: @Juan I thought about this approach but the JSON structure is not a `List` and is Object example `{"branch": {
    "nyc": {},
    "boston": {},
    "charlotte": {}
    }}` hence I posted this doubt. Is it possible using `ArrayList`?.

Comment: You are right, I thought I had seen it as an array. If you can't change how the json is generated perhaps the only option you have is to use reflection to add the Location attributes.

Comment: @Juan can you provide an example of using reflection for this problem, or point me to the right resource.

Comment: I was just checking, but it seems you can only work on existing fields and methods using reflection, no luck adding new fields. Sorry.

Comment: @Juan I am considering to change the `JSON` structure in this case `{"branch": [ { "nyc": {} }, { "boston": {} }, { "charlotte": {} } ]}`  how can I read all locations inside `Branch` class using `ArrayList<Location>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169001/discussion-between-aniks-and-juan).